# Removing duplication by overriding methods in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a simple ruby snippet to detect palindromes in English and another class to detect palindromes in another language.

This first code snippet works as expected.

```
# Defines a Phrase class (inheriting from String).
class Phrase < String

  #process string for palindrome testing
  def processor(string)
    self.downcase
  end

  def processed_content
    processor(self)
  end

  def palindrome?
    processed_content == processed_content.reverse
  end
end

#define a translated Phrase
class TranslatedPhrase < Phrase
  attr_accessor :translation

  def initialize(content, translation)
    super(content)
    @translation = translation
  end

  #process translation for palindrome testing
  def processed_content
    processor(translation)
  end
end
```

However, this second snippet does not.

```
# Defines a Phrase class (inheriting from String).
class Phrase < String

  def processor(string)
    self.downcase
  end
  # Returns content for palindrome testing.
  def processed_content
    processor(self)
  end

  # Returns true for a palindrome, false otherwise.
  def palindrome?
    processed_content == processed_content.reverse
  end
end

# Defines a translated Phrase.
class TranslatedPhrase < Phrase
  attr_accessor :translation

  def initialize(content, translation)
    super(content)
    @translation = translation
  end

  # Processes the translation for palindrome testing.
  def processed_content
    processor(translation)
  end
end
```

When I run the following code. I get **TRUE** for the first example and **False** for the second example.

```
frase = TranslatedPhrase.new("recognize", "reconocer")
frase.palindrome?
```

The difference being I have introduced a **Processor** method to remove duplication of calling downcase.

What could be the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: We need some input to locate the problem, any running example?

Comment: Hi @halfelf I have edited the question to make it more straight forward

Comment: @Ben: add input data and results, expected and actual.

Comment: I mean how did you creat `TranslatedPhrase` instance?

Comment: JFYI, your `processor` methods ignore their argument.

Comment: Your two snippets are exactly the same. And when you say "it doesn't work", how? What error do get, coming from which line?

Comment: @halfelf like this `frase = TranslatedPhrase.new("recognize", "reconocer")`

Comment: @maxpleaner when I run `frase = TranslatedPhrase.new("recognize", "reconocer")'` in the first example, followed by `frase.palindrome?` I get true. In the second example I get false.

Comment: "in the first I get true, in the second I get false" - impossible. These two snippets are identical.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev check the answer provided below. It explains the issue.

Comment: @Ben: my comment hinting at the same thing was earlier. And it's still impossible for these two snippets to behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

method `processor` should be changed like:

```rb
  def processor(string)
    string.downcase
  end
```

now it `downcase` self instead of the parameter.

that's why below doesn't work

```rb
  def processed_content
    processor(translation)
  end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I get it, thanks for clarification about the comment about the parameter.